# How to get rid of "I have no name"?

Tags: linux

I accidentally set 777 permissions with `chmod` on the `/var/` directory on a Linux server.

Now I'm observing the following errors:

```
id: cannot find name for user ID 673910804
id: cannot find name for group ID 673710593
id: cannot find name for user ID 673910804
[I have no name!@tb-linux-d08 ~]$
```

Please help me get rid of this error.

Comment: Can you post your `/etc/passwd` content related to your account.

Comment: And also check permission of `/etc/passwd` file. It should be 644 that means `-rw-r--r--.`

Comment: If this is a chroot jail, you need to copy the NSS libraries in addition to `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/nsswitch.conf` being present and world-readable. On Debian and Ubuntu systems, you can do that with `cp -p --parent /lib/*/libns{l,s_}* /path/to/jail`

Answer (score 5):

The `/var` permissions are either a red herring or incidental. For the uid-to-name lookup to work, the following must be correct, in order:

- `/etc/nsswitch.conf` needs to have permissions 0644, owner root:root.
- The `passwd` entry in that file needs to be correct - given the very large IDs, you're probably not using just the local password file, but some ldap or AD setup? Make sure that it's listed, and listed early on.
- The service that actually provides your identities needs to be up and running and accepting your queries - for local users, that means that `/etc/passwd` must have permissions 0644 and owner root:root.
- The client library for your identity service may have permissions requirements for its config, cache, or both. This is where the `/var` permissions would come in, but without knowing more about what you use for authentication, that's not possible to troubleshoot. At a minimum, make sure that `/var` itself has permissions 0755, owner root:root; directories it contains should be owned by either an obvious system user/group (e.g. "mail" for `/var/mail`) or root, and not be world-writable (with the exception of `/var/tmp`, if it exists, which should be root-owned and have permissions 1777).

If that doesn't help (and even if it does), please provide more information about your auth system - LDAP, samba, AD (via what?), or something else.

Comment: The user name is read from /etc/passwd. So every user must have permission to read that file for name lookup to work. If you change the ownership and depending on who to, other errors/warnings occur because of other services complaining about security.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

1. [chown](http://ss64.com/bash/chown.html)
2. [chgrp](http://ss64.com/bash/chgrp.html)

You can use these to reset the correct user/group for the permissions you need on your folder.
You should also [chown](http://ss64.com/bash/chown.html) the folder to ensure the permissions are back to what is needed for your implementation.

More than likely you will need you set the permissions to something like 600/700 with root as the user. But once again, I don't know what you're doing in that directory so it depends on what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the 'I have no name!' prompt on my laptop (Ubuntu 14.04) at the office today. My laptop uses pbis (Likewise) to connect to AD.

Turns out that my password had expired. It was odd that I didn't get any previous warnings that it was going to expire. After a couple of reboots and logging in did a statement finally indicate that my password expired.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once, a misbehaving script had modified permissions of several files in /etc/ on my machine.

The solution was to restore permissions on /etc/nsswitch.conf:

```
$ chmod 644 /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the user is able to read the "/etc/passwd" file.

I have faced a similar issue before where my passwd file didn't had read access in the group & other's field.

Try hitting the below command

```
chmod 644 /etc/passwd
```